# Cannot bulk load because the file ... could not be opened. Operating system error code 58(The specified server cannot perform the requested operation)

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, stored-procedures

I am trying to run stored procedure from web application hosted on IIS with service account. The service account use windows authentication. When trying to run the stored procedure it should read a file from shared folder and return byte array.

When trying to run the stored procedure with SQL Login account it works fine, but with windows authentication it throws the error that "Cannot bulk load because the file ... could not be opened. Operating system error code 58(The specified server cannot perform the requested operation)".

Comment: Might be a Kerberos double-hop issue where the IIS account has authenticated, SQL Server is using the IIS account credentials to access the share, but authenticating with this token fails. Troubleshooting such issues is not fun.

Comment: If it is a double hop issue, your network administrator is going to be the person to talk to.

Comment: I am trying to find workaround and...
what I am trying is from the stored-procedure to create dynamically SQL job which is running through proxy account. The job subsystem is TSQL and tries to read the file. In this case I am facing the error "A proxy account is not allowed for a Transact-SQL subsystem."

Comment: If you are OK with the procedure running in the context of another account (that is, you *don't* want it to impersonate the IIS account), you can simply use `EXECUTE AS` in the procedure, rather than create a brand new job.